# ruby on rails - dealing with variables not being set or not existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there is a better way to check if a variable exists, currently I do this

```
if !params['attribute']['institution'].blank?
```

But if attribute doesn't exist then a error is thrown.

I saw `.try()` but couldn't see how it would work in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `present?` or `presence` which was recently described by a [blog post](http://olabini.com/blog/2011/01/use-presence/) by Ola Bini.

Answer (score 2):

```
if params['attribute'] && params['attribute']['institution']
```

Not the prettiest, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if params['attribute'].has_key? 'institution'`